# How to customize a plugin?

Tags: plugins

When I need any functionality, I use a plugin or a snippet code inside `functions.php`. But now, I have a plugin that accomplishes my expected functionality, but I have to replace (not add) some code on it. The problem is that if I upgrade the plugin in the future, my changes may be overridden.

The code is too large to add it on `functions.php`, and create my own plugin would take much time. What is the better way to proceed in this case?

*As a note, I thought that I may could disable the upgrade button for that plugin, although it doesn't seem the better way to proceed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin has action hooks or filters you can make your changes from your theme without modifying the plugin itself.

an action hook:

`do_action( 'my_plugin_do_something' );`

a filter:
`apply_filters( 'my_plugin_filter_something', $something );`

If the plugin doesn't have those where you need them, you could try suggesting them to the author. For example if the author uses Github.com for developing the plugin and you sent a pull request with the suggested changes you'd have a pretty good chance of having the author add your changes to the core code.

Comment: I fear that the author doesn't use any public repo for developing. And no filter or action hooks seem to be implemented. I guess the only way is to create a new plugin based on it (or disable the upgrade button for that plugin if possible) .

Comment: That's unfortunate. Have you tried contacting the author? Almost assuredly she must have a website available (listed in the plugin header). Is the plugin being actively maintained?  Personally, I am always open to a user sending me improved code.

Comment: Good luck. Your other options are pretty much 1. Hack the plugin (change the title in the header and it will not try to upload). Of course, then you are stuck. 2. Fork the plugin and create your own version. That's the beauty of open-source after all.

Comment: I'm finally doing my own version, but I've used the "rename option" for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with your own custom plugin. Which will extend that plugin with hooks.

There was lot of plugin skeletons available. [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) and [WordPress-Plugin-Skeleton](https://github.com/iandunn/WordPress-Plugin-Skeleton).

Use this for faster and structured development.